# Given a RepoItemInfo, how can I retrieve the corresponding Ranorex.Adapter from the repository?

Tags: ranorex

I am given a `RepoItemInfo` object, and would like to retrieve the corresponding adapter from my repository.

`RepoItemInfo.FindAdapter<T>` finds or creates and adapter of type `T`, however my code is supposed to be general and should not assume a particular type. Instead, I would like to retrieve the adapter specified in my repository as denoted by `RepoItemInfo.FullName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution via reflection.

```
public static class RanorexExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an adapter for the associated repository item
    /// as defined in the repository.
    /// 
    /// If you know the adapter type, or want to use a different
    /// one, you can use <see cref="FindAdapter{T}" /> instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemInfo">The RepoItemInfo object</param>
    /// <returns>The adapter.</returns>
    public static Adapter GetAdapter(this RepoItemInfo itemInfo)
    {
        var folder = itemInfo.ParentFolder;
        Adapter adapter = (Adapter)folder.GetType().GetProperty(itemInfo.Name).GetValue(folder);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This solution has some disadvantages. In some cases `.GetValue(folder)` causes TIMEOUT

Comment: Hi @hellboy sorry to hear. Worked fine for us. Is it reproducible? Can you conclude a certain pattern/common aspect of those that timeout and those that do not?

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
repoItemInfo.CreateAdapter<WebElement>(true)
```

if it is just for something like click

Comment: Could you explain a bit what the true parameter does? Thanks. Could I also use this approach if I do not now the type `WebElement` beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Use simply this;

```
repoItemInfo.FindAdapter<Unknown>().Element.SetAttributeValue("Text", Value);
```